# Array-declaration issue in Python

Tags: python, arrays, matrix

I have trouble declaring a two-dimensional list in Python. Below are two different matrices; A and R. When changing the content of a single cell I am successful in the R-matrix, but not so much in the A-matrix, as the value-input affect the entire column and not only the single cell. 
Why does this happen? I would prefer the A-style of declaring the matrix.

```
n=6

A = [[0]*n]*n    
R=[[0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0]]

R[1][1]=5
A[1][1]=5

print(R)
print(A)
```

The output from the two operations is:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
[[0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: The `*` operator on a list creates a list of references to the same list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A = [[0]*n]*n creates multiple copies of the same list. This is why changing one affects every other one

Comment: Thanks. Is there a fix for it?

Comment: @Enthuziast Please see the linked duplicate. This question has already been asked+answered before